# How to retry db transaction in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to update 4 tables inside foreach loop  it gives deadlock exception .for that I used `db::transaction()` now it is not giving exception but missed some records to update. Is there any way to retry to update those records? Note: this process is inside `queue`

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($invoice) {
                StoragePeriod::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)->where('invoice_id', null)->whereDate('end_date_time', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);
                 Consignment::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>', date('2021-03-04'))->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))->where('finalize', 0)->where('is_repeat', 0)->where('invoice_id', null)->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);
                PurchaseOrder::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>', date('2021-03-04'))->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))->where('invoice_id', null)->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);
                SaleOrder::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>', date('2021-03-04'))->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))->where('invoice_id', null)->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);
            }, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this approach because it has more control over code.
After php raise an exception, it fall in the catch section and i know what kind of error i've dealing with.

```php
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
                StoragePeriod::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)
                    ->where('invoice_id', null)
                    ->whereDate('end_date_time', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))
                    ->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);

                Consignment::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)
                    ->whereDate('created_at', '>', date('2021-03-04'))
                    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))
                    ->where('finalize', 0)
                    ->where('is_repeat', 0)
                    ->where('invoice_id', null)
                    ->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);

                PurchaseOrder::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '>', date('2021-03-04'))
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))
                   ->where('invoice_id', null)
                   ->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);

                SaleOrder::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '>', date('2021-03-04'))
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->end_date)))
                   ->where('invoice_id', null)
                   ->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);

    DB::commit();
} catch (Throwable $throwable) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $throwable;
}
```

Comment: This process is in queue and can happen any time. I just want it to retry again if it fails. just catching exception won't help

Comment: Can i see your whole job class that executes this transaction?